# Can Not Hand-code Simple SOAP Request from WSDL

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl, salesforce

I am writing the client-side (iOS, Swift) of a Salesforce-based web application, and I need to access a custom API via SOAP.

I am struggling to assemble, by hand, a SOAP request in XML, based on the WSDL I received from the server side.

I am completely inexperienced in XML/SOAP, and are just now beginning to understand what the whole WSDL thing is about. I have read [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-understand-web-services2/ws-understand-web-services2.html) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_wsdl.asp), among other introductory online docs, but I'm still struggling to grasp all the new concepts.

Because of confidentiality reasons(exposing the internals of my web application), I am reluctant to use any online automated generator like [this one](http://www.wsdl2swift.com).

---

This are the relevant (I think) parts of my WSDL:

```
<definitions targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/[WSDL_File_Name]" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:tns="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/[WSDL_File_Name]">

    <!-- ... -->

    <message name="executeXmlRequest">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:executeXml" />
    </message>

    <!-- ... -->

    <binding name="[WSDL_File_Name]Binding" type="tns:[WSDL_File_Name]PortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="executeXml">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
                <input>
                    <soap:header use="literal" part="SessionHeader" message="tns:Header"/>
                    <soap:header use="literal" part="CallOptions" message="tns:Header"/>
                    <soap:header use="literal" part="DebuggingHeader" message="tns:Header"/>
                    <soap:header use="literal" part="AllowFieldTruncationHeader" message="tns:Header"/>
                    <soap:body use="literal" parts="parameters"/>
                </input>
                <output>
                    <!-- skipped -->
                </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
<service name="[WSDL_File_Name]Service">
    <documentation></documentation>
        <port binding="tns:[WSDL_File_Name]Binding" name="[WSDL_File_Name]">
            <soap:address location="https://XXX.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/[WSDL_File_Name]"/>
        </port>
 </service>
```

(I have obfuscated **[WSDL_File_Name]** -the name of the WSDL file, which also occurs as a prefix here and there).

**In particular,** I have trouble understanding the message part:

```
<message name="executeXmlRequest">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:executeXml" />
</message>
```

In most examples I've found on the web (e.g., [here](http://crunchify.com/basic-wsdl-structure-understanding-wsdl-explained/) and [here](https://www.w3.org/2001/03/14-annotated-WSDL-examples.html#xsd_def_GetEndorsingBoarder)), it is typically `name="body"` (*not* `"parameters"`), so I am not really sure about how to translate this into the actual SOAP request's XML body. I've tried this request body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <urn:SessionHeader>
            <urn:sessionId>[My OAuth 2.0 Token]</urn:sessionId>
        </urn:SessionHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <tns:executeXml xmlns:tns="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/[WSDL_File_Name]">

        <!-- PAYLOAD HERE (more XML) -->

        </tns:executeXml>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

...but I get the **"Argument 1 cannot be null"** error response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/[WSDL_File_Name]">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <executeXmlResponse>
            <result>
            <!-- 
                 The following inline-XML came from the server with
                 all entities escaped (e.g., "&lt;" instead of "<"); 
                 I replaced them back here for legibility. 
            -->
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <response>
                <success>false</success>
                <exception>
                    <typeName>System.NullPointerException</typeName>
                    <message>Argument 1 cannot be null</message>
                    <stackTrace>Class.[Inbound_Service_Class].Message.<init>: line 271, column 1
    Class.[Inbound_Service_Class].parse: line 47, column 1
    Class.[Inbound_Service_Class].receive: line 29, column 1
    Class.[WSDL_File_Name].executeXml: line 18, column 1
                    </stackTrace>
                </exception>
            </response>
            <!-- 
                Originally escaped entitied end here 
            -->
            </result>
        </executeXmlResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

(again, app-specific class names/etc. obfuscated in square brackets)

So, **What should my request body look like?**

---

**Clarification:** The string "parameters" appears  (as an xml attribute value) a total of **three** times in the whole WSDL file:

1. Input message: `<message name="executeXmlRequest"><part name="parameters"...`
2. Output message: `<message name="executeXmlResponse"><part name="parameters"...`
3. Binding: `<binding...> ... <soap:body use="literal" parts="parameters"/>...`

---

**SOLUTION:**

Guided by the contents of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422999/433373) and re-reading all the docs (for example, [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_complextype.asp)), I finally realized that the contents of the `tns:executeXml` tag are specified in the Types section of my WSDL (Sorry I didn't post this part in my question. The Types section is huge and I skipped it entirely):

```
<xsd:element name="executeXml">
    <xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="reqXml" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
                      <!-- ^ THIS GUY... -->
     </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
```

...so I figured that this translates into a SOAP request with body envelope like this:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <tns:executeXml xmlns:tns=\"http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/[WSDL_File_Name]">

       <!-- ...BECOMES THIS ELEMENT: -->
       <tns:reqXml><!-- (MY ESCAPED XML PAYLOAD GOES HERE) --></tns:reqXml>

    </tns:executeXml>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Now I'm just getting application-specific error messages regarding the contents of the XML I'm posting, but that I can solve on my own. I seem to be getting to the API successfully.

I'm sorry @Sundar that I didn't provide enough information before. I have accepted your answer because it led me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tools like SOAPUI , there is free version , point it to the WSDL and create a new soap project , you can then create a soap request with dummy values , take it and replace with your values. It is not possible to say what should be in the request xml with our having your complete WSDL , that is the point of the contract isn't it.

But you error seems to be very specific that you are not sending a null value for a particular parameter which should not be null , I think

Comment: like I said, I can not point a free tool to the WSDL. Also, I thought I appended all the relevant parts of my WSDL. Basically, I am supposed to embed some XML that the server side API will parse, so there's not much to specify other than the name of the message and the service URL...? I'm just not sure about the exact format to "embed" it (other than e.g. escape entities, etc.)

Comment: Also, I don't have an URL fo my WSDL that isn't behind a login screen (I think). I got it from the control panel.

Comment: Do you have the wsdl file , you can point to that , there is simply no way to write a request without seeing a WSDL file in my humble opinion

Comment: I have pasted most of the WSDL file in my question. Like I said, what I believe are the relevant parts.